# Translates of abelian subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $A$ is an abelian variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. I'm confused about the notion of translates of abelian subvarieties. I looked over a few related papers, but I couldn't find a precise algebro-geometric definition. People simply used $x+B$, and I assume they are interested in functor of points. In my opinion, given a point $x:\mathrm{Spec}k'\rightarrow A$, a translate should live in the base change $A_{k'}$. Namely there is an abelian subvariety $B$ of $A_{k'}$ such that $x+B$ is our translate.

If $x$ is a closed point of $A$ and $B\subset A$, then $x+B$ would be a closed subvariety of $A$.

If $x$ is not closed, a translate through $x$ is really something lives in a base change of $A$ (so that $x$ becomes a closed point in the base change).

I'm wondering about the following question:

Mordell exceptional locus of a closed subvariety $X\subset A$ is defined as the union of images of positive-dimensional translates inside $X$. Do we need to consider the translates through non closed points? Namely, if we take the union of translates through closed points, will that give us the same thing?

Comment: Usually, when one speaks of "translate of an abelian subvariety" it really is in the sense "translate of an abelian subvariety by a closed point". To answer your question: Let $X\subset A$ be a closed subvariety over an abelian variety $A$ over $k$. Assume $k$ is algebraically closed (of characteristic zero?). Let $Sp(X)$ be the union of positive-dimensional translates (by closed points of $A$) of abelian subvarieties contained in $X$. Let $L/k$ be an extension of algebraically closed fields. Then $Sp(X)_L = Sp(X_L)$, where $Sp(X_L)$ is the union of ...

Comment: ...the positive-dimensional translates of abelian subvarieties by closed points of $A_L$ contained in $X_L$. Thus, the Mordell exceptional locus behaves well with respect to field extensions. You can prove this using spreading out and specialization arguments; see also Proposition 3.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.12187

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: That's really helpful! Thanks a lot! So I assume if we want an argument as Proposition 3.7, we would need to know $Sp(X_L)$ is closed？Do you think there is a way to do it without assuming closedness of the set (so $Sp(X)_L$ just means the inverse image of $Sp(X)$ in $X_L$)?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: Also, if you have a nontrivial map from a group variety to $X$, would it factor through $Sp(X)$?

Comment: The fact that $Sp(X)$ is closed in $X$ was proven first by Kawamata; see Thm. 4 in Y. Kawamata, On Bloch’s conjecture, Invent. Math. 57 (1980), 97-100. Ueno subsequently proved that $Sp(X)\neq X$ if and only if $X$ is of general type. Similar statements are true for closed subvarieties of semi-abelian varieties; see Abramovich http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1994__90_1_37_0/ ...cont'd below...

Comment: If you want to avoid using the fact that Sp(X) is closed, you will have to think a bit harder.  I will look into it once I have some more time if you really want to know if it is possible to argue without using that Sp(X) is closed....con't below...

Comment: Finally, I claim that Sp(X) equals the "groupless-exceptional locus" as defined in Definition 12.4. of https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11981 . To prove this, you have to combine some of the statements in  arxiv.org/abs/1909.12187 with the following fact: If $B$ is an abelian variety and $B\dashrightarrow X$ is a rational map, then $B\dashrightarrow X$ is a morphism (i.e., everywhere defined). (This is because $B$ is smooth and $X$ has no rational curves.) ..con'd below

Comment: ...This means that images of rational maps of abelian varieties are images of morphisms of abelian varieties. But these images are translates of subabelian varieties (by closed points!) of $A $ because morphisms of abelian varieties are homomorphisms up to translation.

Comment: Does this answer all your questions? If so, then I can make the above comments into an answer.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar: That's very very helpful! Thanks again! Yes please make it into an answer:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when one speaks of "translate of an abelian subvariety" it really is in the sense "translate of an abelian subvariety by a closed point".

To answer your question: Let $X\subset A$ be a closed subvariety of an abelian variety $A$ over $k$. Assume that $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic zero. Let $Sp(X)$ be the union of positive-dimensional translates (by closed points of $A$) of abelian subvarieties contained in $X$.   Kawamata proved that $Sp(X)$ is closed in $X$; see Thm. 4 in Y. Kawamata, On Bloch’s conjecture, Invent. Math. 57 (1980), 97-100.

**Side remark.** Ueno   proved that  $Sp(X) \neq X$ if and only if $X$ is of general type. Similar statements are true   for closed subvarieties of semi-abelian varieties in positive characteristic; see Abramovich numdam.org/item/CM_1994__90_1_37_0

Let $L/k$    be an extension of algebraically closed fields. Then $Sp(X)_L = Sp(X_L)$, where $Sp(X_L)$    is the union of 
the positive-dimensional translates of abelian subvarieties of $A_L$   contained in $X_L$. Thus, the  "special" locus of $X$ behaves well with respect to field extensions. Let me explain how to prove this in a more general context.

Let $\Delta^{gr}_X$  be the groupless-exceptional locus. That is, $\Delta^{gr}_X$ is the Zariski closure of the union of the images of non-constant morphisms $U\to X$, where $U$ is a dense open subset of a connected finite type group scheme $G$ over $k$ such that $\mathrm{codim}_G(G\setminus U)\geq 2$. 
 Then, $\Delta^{gr}_X =Sp(X)$; see Theorem 13.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.11981.pdf .
To  prove this equality of sets, use   the following three facts:

> > 1)   every rational map $B\dashrightarrow X$ with $B$ an abelian variety extends to a morphism $B\to X$ (use that $X$ has no rational curves).
> >
> > 2)   if $G$ is a connected linear algebraic group, then every rational map $G\dashrightarrow X $ is constant. This is because linear algebraic groups are covered by (non-compact) rational curves.
> >
> > 3) The image of a morphism of abelian varieties $B\to A$ is the translate of a  abelian subvariety of $A$.

In the absence of an ambient abelian variety, the general statement you are looking for is the following:

> > **Proposition 3.7 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.12187**
> >
> > *Let $L/k$ be an extension of algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero. Let X be a proper variety over $k$. Then $(\Delta_X^{gr})_L = \Delta^{gr}_{X_L}$.*

Comment: I'm thinking about the following example: if $X=E\times C$ where $E$ is an elliptic curve and $C$ is a curve of genus $2$. Then $Sp(X)$ is supposed to be $X$. But the union of translates by closed points seems not including the codim $2$ generic point? I'm probably missing a point here. Could you help me out?

Comment: @ggttttll Sp(X) is scheme-theoretically really the *closure* of the closed subset (of the variety $X(k)$) given by the union of translates of positive-dimensional abelian subvarieties. It is then clear that $Sp(X)  = X$ as a scheme if $X = E \times C$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! Take care!